# Gmail web, is there a plugin to tag email with a direct button?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

Do you know a browser plugin (or something else ?) to add some labels as direct button (no menu) in the web interface ?

For example, I would like to mark my email in gmail and directly click on a button *mycompany* on the right side of "Mark as read" button or "More" button.

Comment: Would a keyboard shortcut (they're very quick) do for your purposes, or are you specifically wanting to click on something?

Comment: A keyboard shortcut would be nice. Is it easy to code ? Do you know some good resources about it ? It would be a good answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A way to quickly add labels to your messages in Gmail *without having to install anything* is through keyboard shortcuts.

When one or more messages are selected in your Inbox, you can press the <kbd>L</kbd> key, which will automatically open up your list of labels. If you type the first few letters of the label you want and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Return</kbd> (whichever it's called on your computer), the label that matches those letters will be added to all selected messages.

This is a very quick method, as you only need to type the first few unique characters of the label name.  For example, if you have three labels starting with "b" -- belugas, business, and bunnies, you would only have to type:

- <kbd>b</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to add the Beluga label
- <kbd>bu</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to add the Bunnies label (it's ordered alphabetically)
- <kbd>bus</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to add the Business label

So, to add a label to all selected messages, you could potentially do it by barely lifting a finger with three quick keystrokes:

- <kbd>L</kbd> to bring up the label function,
- <kbd>m</kbd> to add the label "mybusiness" (or you could add a number to the beginning like "1 mybusiness" if you have a bunch of other m-labels)
- <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Or you could just press <kbd>m</kbd> and then use your arrow keys to navigate through the list from there, if you wanted to be less efficient. :)

**NOTE:** To use this method, make sure your keyboard shortcuts are turned on. To do this:

1. In Gmail, click on the Gear in the top-right corner
2. Select "Mail settings"
3. In the "General" section, select the "Keyboard shortcuts on" option (near the top of the list)
4. Click "Save changes" at the bottom of the page

**Tips:**

If you want to use your keyboard to navigate through your inbox and select messages for adding label (instead of using your mouse to click the box on each message you want selected):

- press <kbd>j</kbd> to move down the list of messages, and <kbd>k</kbd> to move up the list
- once navigating through your inbox, you can select/check-off a message by pressing <kbd>x</kbd>
- for more keyboard shortcuts, press <kbd>?</kbd> while in your inbox for a menu of all the commands

Comment: Thanks for this detail howto, i wasn't expecting so much. You convince me to start using keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @Alex. I completely missed that there was a tag for keys.